# Check if every element in 2D numpy array is in set

Tags: python, numpy, set, where-clause

I want to efficiently check, for every element in a numpy array, whether that element is present in a set.  For example:

```
segmask = np.array([[1,2,3,4]])
numbers = {2,4}
check_if_in_set(numbers, segmask)
```

should return

```
[[False  True False  True]]
```

or similar.

Answer (score 2):

`np.isin(segmask, list(numbers))`

will give you the result you want.  According to [the isin documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html), you *must convert the set to a list* before feeding it into the isin function.